# Sharing a temporary client certificate store between multiple processes

Tags: ssl-certificate, client-certificates

Suppose **Process A** creates a temporary client certificate store, then launches **Process B**, passing the inherited cert store handle via some kind of inter process communication, then **Process A** exits. (see below)

When **Process B** starts running, it fetches the cert store handle and tries processing the temporary client store.

The question is: "Can a temporary cert store created in parent **Process A** (which exits) still be accessible by child **Process B**?" Thanks!

```
Process A
+--------------------------------------------------+
| CreateFile("certificate.pfx",...)                |
| ReadFile(hFile,...)                              |
| Create CRYPT_DATA_BLOB                           |
| PFXImportCertStore(&cryptBlob,...)               |
| CreateProcess(Process B hCertStore,...,TRUE,...) |
| (TRUE indicates new process inherits hCertStore) |
| Process Exits                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------+


Process B
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Get handle hCertStore using Inter-Process Comms  |
| CertFindCertificateInStore{hCertStore,...)       |
| Process the temporary cert store...              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran a test, passing the temp cert store handle from **Process A** to **Process B** and was greeted with a crash dump:

```
    STACK_TEXT:  
    00000017`7df4fcc0 00007ffa`655574c6     : 00000017`7df4fd30 00000017`7df4fd30 00000017`7df4fd10 00000000`ffffffff : crypt32!AutoResyncStore+0x10
    00000017`7df4fd20 00007ff7`23c943cd     : 0000016d`0dc53a2e 00000000`00000000 00007ff7`23cac7c2 00000000`0118b2d8 : crypt32!CertFindCertificateInStore+0x56
    00000017`7df4fd70 0000016d`0dc53a2e     : 00000000`00000000 00007ff7`23cac7c2 00000000`0118b2d8 00000000`00000000 : HelloWorld64!WinMain+0x121
    00000017`7df4fd78 00000000`00000000     : 00007ff7`23cac7c2 00000000`0118b2d8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x0000016d`0dc53a2e

SYMBOL_NAME:  crypt32!AutoResyncStore+10

MODULE_NAME: crypt32

IMAGE_NAME:  crypt32.dll

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_crypt32.dll!AutoResyncStore

OS_VERSION:  10.0.18362.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10
```

Looks like it's not possible to access a temporary cert store using a shared handle from another process. As a workaround, I'll look into passing the PFX BLOB as follows:

1. Pass the PFX BLOB (i.e., the pfx file bytes) via IPC to another process.
2. Create a global shared named memory map for the BLOB, so any process with that
   memory handle can access it and process the cert.

Thanks.